# What's the difference b/w __raw_readl/__raw_writel and readl/writel in linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, driver

What's the difference b/w `__raw_readl/__raw_writel` and `readl/writel` in linux kernel? It is said `readl/writel` is safer than `__raw_readl/__raw_writel`, then why do we still use `__raw_readl/__raw_writel` ?

Under what circumstances should we use this: `__raw_readl/__raw_writel` or `readl/writel` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It *seems* to be the case that

- raw denotes native byte ordering, non-raw means little-endian
- the __ prefix alternatives don't include memory barriers

See [this LKML discussion](http://lkml.org/lkml/2008/6/3/5) and also the comments in [linux/arch/arm/include/asm/io.h](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3/arch/arm/include/asm/io.h)