# Explanation of function used in embeded systems

Tags: embedded, arm

*Can anyone exactly explain what the function '__raw_writel' do and what are the arguments of   '__raw_writel'*

Comment: can you show us the code ?

Comment: When confronted with odd but unique macros in code (especially without any context!), a web search is a good idea.  In this case it quickly turned up the following which you might want to see for some links to interesting resources, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818657/whats-the-difference-b-w-raw-readl-raw-writel-and-readl-writel-in-linux-ker

Comment: yes mux sure here it is int" pinMuxUpp()
{
 __raw_writel(0x44440000,PINMUX13);

 __raw_writel(0x44444400,PINMUX14);

 __raw_writel(0x44444444,PINMUX15);

 __raw_writel(0x44444444,PINMUX16);

 __raw_writel(0x44444444,PINMUX17);

 __raw_writel(0x00444444,PINMUX18);
 
 return SUCCESS;
}" The code

Comment: @auselen,@DocMax and all othere with great respect i have asked about explanation of the function __raw_writel and about its arguments and the link which refere my question to another question asked on stack over flow is diffrenet in a sense that i dont know aboutknow a very little about the function but one who have asked about difference b/w functions is known about its arguments i think and the answers provided for that question doest not define the answer for my question thanks all in advance for considerin my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what implementation or where you are using it. But judging from [this](http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch08.html), it is use to write data into I/O memory and as it is also mention at  [What's the difference b/w __raw_readl/__raw_writel and readl/writel in linux kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818657/whats-the-difference-b-w-raw-readl-raw-writel-and-readl-writel-in-linux-ker),

- raw denotes native byte ordering, non-raw means little-endian
- the __prefix alternatives don't include memory barriers

Also, you should try to look at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/microblaze/include/asm/io.h#L66 to figure out more details and arguments for the function.

Comment: yes i know but i dont know about the argumensts what are its arguments

Comment: __raw_writel(unsigned value, address), hope its helpful.

Comment: i know a litle bit about it that first argument is i think is for the addres of the memroy and second one is the register value in which this addre is to be saved but i am not sure  so thats why i have posted this question on stack over flow

Comment: Thankyou @Aamir Abro "The world is Gold If you Are Bold"